# EEG filtration via EMG

Tags: filters, adaptive-filters, eeg, emg, regression

i got little problem. I'm trying to detect HFOs in single channel EEG (the recording is multichannel, but there is not enough channels to use ICA) for my diploma thesis experiment and i want to first preprocess the intracranial EEG signal (rats with electrodes placed in CA2 thalamus) by filtering movement artifacts.
I also got two channel EMG recorded simultaneously with iEEG signal. And i got no ground truth data to validate specific method for filtration. Correlation coef between EMG and EEG is kindy low (circa 0.05)(so it is not suitable to use regression based filtration???). So Im trying to do this by RLS adaptive filter, with EMG as reference signal (i don't need online algorithm). Is this method ok for my needs or do you know better approach to do it? Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to our stack exchange. It would help if you could explain all the three letter acronyms that you are using. They may be obvious to you, but they are probably not to most participants here who come from different fields.

Comment: HFO - high frequency oscillations
EEG - electroencephalography
ICA - independent component analysis
CA2 - brain area
EMG - electromyography
iEEG - intracranial EEG
RLS - recursive least squares